# 1st - How does Heroku interact with a database (sqlite) 2nd - How can I obtain the version of database that is on Heroku?

Tags: database, sqlite, heroku, web-applications

I had a very hard time trying to find solutions to this problem online, probably because I do not know how to phrase this weird problem. I also could not reach out to Heroku as their support team only serves paid customers. I would really appreciate help from anyone.

**Some context:**

I have recently started experimenting with Heroku and deployed my first web app (Python, Flask, SQLite3) via GitHub. It works as intended, I am even able to interact with my database (add/delete/update). However, after making an update to my code locally and pushing it to GitHub, I realised that when my web app got built again by Heroku with the updates, the changes I made to the SQLite database is reverted back the initial, local version. (aka I lost the updates I made during testing).

**So here comes the first question:**

How does Heroku actually interact with the database? Does it create a copy of all my code from GitHub and runs it locally on their servers? (Since no changes to the database are reflected in my GitHub Repo despite successful updates to the database values through the web app).

**And if so, this is the second question:**

Is there any way for me to get this "updated version" of my database from Heroku side so I can download it locally before I make and push any updates to my code, so as not to erase all the updates to the database that a user might have made through the web app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku app database resetting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456932/heroku-app-database-resetting)

Comment: Don't use SQLite on Heroku (see the dupe I just proposed). Instead, use a client-server database like PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you for the replies! Can I assume that the actual only solution is to change a database that Heroku directly supports like PostgreSQL? Even if I am able to do that, how would I have Heroku interact with it? I do apologise for my cluelessness, for I really just started out looking into these platforms and I only really learnt Python at the moment..